# pathinfo com cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Olá, fiz um sistema de upload de imagens, em que, as imagens salvas, são salvas com `$id_o.$extensao` = 1_o.jpg , agora, estou criando um elemento, que com esse nome de imagem, me retorne o caminho relativo dessa imagem, o problema é que meu pathinfo(dirname) está me retornando apenas um ' . '(ponto), se alguém puder me dar uma luz. Agradeço  desde já.

```
foreach ($fotos as $valor => $foto){
    $extension = pathinfo(WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'galeria' . DS . "{$foto['Foto']['id']}_o.{$foto['Foto']['extension']}",PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
    echo $extension;
}
```

Comment: O segundo atributo, `PATHINFO_DIRNAME`, irá retornar o diretório atual, que de fato é um `.`, já que você só passou o nome da imagem. Se quer o caminho relativo, você precisa passar todo o caminho no primeiro parâmetro.

Comment: Certo, alterei a pergunta, mas no caso, esse é o único jeito de obter o caminho relativo, se no caso, eu não souber qual pasta esse arquivo está, não tem outra maneira de obter esse caminho?

Comment: Bom, com isso, o seu código já funciona da forma que você espera. Ele irá retornar pra você exatamente o que você passou no primeiro parâmetro, exceto o nome do arquivo. Não tem outro jeito de saber, somente com o nome do arquivo, de você saber qual o restante do caminho. Você teria que fazer varrer todos os seus diretório para buscar esse arquivo, o que seria inviável no meu ponto de vista.

Comment: Só mais uma coisa, como que eu montaria um <img src> com echo, usando essas informações?
`$extension = pathinfo(WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'galeria' . DS . "{$foto['Foto']['id']}_o.{$foto['Foto']['extension']}",PATHINFO_DIRNAME);`

No caso o nome da imagem já está ali tb..

Comment: Experimente com `echo $this->Html->image(WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'galeria' . DS . "{$foto['Foto']['id']}_o.{$foto['Foto']['extension']}", array('fullBase' => true));`.

Comment: O caminho que ele está retornando, desde a pasta www/var/..., não está aparecendo mensagem, mas tentei colocar a pasta direto, que é /files/galeria/$img, e a imagem apareceu..